# Why is mfc100.dll required for my Visual Studio 2013 project?

Tags: dll, mfc, visual-studio-2013

I have a Visual Studio project set to use:

- Platform Toolset:  Visual Studio 2010 (v100)
- Use of MFC:        Use Standard Windows Libraries

Yet, if I run this on a computer that does not have mfc100.dll, I get an error that this dll is required. (And Dependency Walker confirms this dll is required.) I'm wondering why this dll is required, when "Use of MFC" is set to "Use Standard Windows Libraries"? (It is NOT set to "Use MFC...")

The platform toolset is set to VS 2010 because a commercial library we use does not support VS 2013 yet.

Comment: Maybe that commercial library uses MFC.

Comment: Use dependency walker tree on the left hand side to navigate to MFC100.dll. It will show how it get there. There will be the whole dependency view that will show which library depends on the dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Easiest way: Check if one of you Projects has "Uses MFC" in the Project Options set
2. Use Depends to check if one of you components (DLLs) that uses mfc100,dll
3. Maybe one of the static libraries requires this. Change the setting of the Linker options to /verbose  this will Show what module uses the MFC libs.