# Is it possible to make an application in Visual Studio 2013 (C++) NOT requiring the VC Redistributable?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, mfc

As basic as this may sound, it seems it's actually NOT possible!

Talking about a totally "empty" application, only containing the `WinMain()` function and including `<windows.h>`. And of course, the "Use of MFC" options in the project is set to "Use Standard Windows Libraries".

Yet the application requires MSVCR120.DLL to run, as if it really uses MFC.

Looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24442478/why-is-mfc100-dll-required-for-my-visual-studio-2013-project) similar thread, but didn't help.

Any idea?

Comment: `MSVCR120.DLL` is not an MFC dll.

Comment: MSVCR120.DLL is not MFC. It is the C Runtime Library.

Comment: With that said you can select static mfc and static runtime and have no dlls. involved.

Comment: *"As basic as this may sound, it seems it's actually NOT!"* - No, this really is very basic, and the answer is: Yes, you can create an application that doesn't use MFC (as demonstrated by your project).

Comment: Even so, it makes the application not self-contained and requires installing the VC Redist pack under some certain OS versions. And that's what I'm trying to avoid. Anyway, edited the title and comment, to improve the question.

Comment: drescherjm, thanks for your reply, but the application is not about to use MFC anyway, while I can't find the "static runtime" option. Does such an option exist in VS 2013? Where exactly? Sorry, can't find it.

Comment: [/MD, /MT, /LD (Use Run-Time Library)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx). Your question still talks about the MFC. Please update it so that it actually makes sense.

Comment: You could find this out from the documentation.  I do think think you have made enough effort.

Answer (score 2):

The option can be found in the Project Properties under **C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library** - set it to *Multi-threaded* or *Multi-threaded Debug* to not depend on the redistributable.